# Scala type safety and type erasure related issue

Tags: scala, type-erasure, type-safety

Lets say I want to construct a list of records, where each record consists of some x number of fields. However, the number of fields and type of the fields are not known at compile time. Only at run-time, we know both the number of fields and type of each field. So to represent this list, I use an List[Array[Any]].

A user should be able to find a record from this list with min (max) value for a certain field.

Here is a highly simplified sample code:

```
class Data(val colValues: List[Array[Any]]) {
  def min(i: Int): Array[Any] = {
    colValues.minBy { _(i) }
  }
}
```

A user should be able to use it this way:

```
val rawData = List(Array("a", 20, "z", "m", 3.0), Array("b", 10, "y", "f", 4.0), Array("c", 40, "z", "m", 2.0))
val d =  new Data(rawData)
val m1 = d.min(1)
val m2 = d.min(4)
```

The above code will not work. Scala gives this error:

> - not enough arguments for method minBy: (implicit cmp: Ordering[Any])Array[Any]. Unspecified value parameter cmp.
> - No implicit Ordering defined for Any.

In fact, as expected, Scala complains anytime I call a higher-order method on this list such as maxBy, sortWith, and sum.

So I modified the code to this:

```
class Data(val colValues: List[Array[Any]]) {
  def withType(x: Any) = x match {
          case i: Int => i
          case l: Long => l
          case f: Float => f
          case d: Double => d
  }

  def min(i: Int): Array[Any] = {
    colValues.minBy { x:Array[Any] => withType(x(i)) }
  }
}
```

This code compiles and runs as expected. However, I feel that there must be a more elegant solution than this. Plus, the above code will not work if the min method is called with an index of a field that is of type String.

Is there a better way to handle type erasure and type safety in case of an Array[Any], where the array stores different types of elements and whose types are known only at run-time?

In addition, is there a better data type than List[Array[Any]] for representing a list of records whose field types (and number) are known only at run-time?

Thank you.

Comment: The reason code above doesn't work is **not** type erasure.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is that you don't have a correct `Ordering` instance in implicit scope. The reason one doesn't exist is `Ordering[Any]` is non-sensical. Even if we had such an instance what purpose would it serve, what does it mean to compare a `String` and `Int`? Or an `Object` and a `List`? You can make up an ordering but it would be useless because there is no way to obtain anything interesting about something of the type `Any`. There are some complicated ways to achieve what you want, but this seems indicative of a design problem, you may want to try to rethink your approach.

Comment: Please remember that the type is known at run-time and for each position in a record, the type is the same anywhere in the list. In other words, if the first field is of type Int in record #1, the first field will be of type Int in all other records. So we will never compare a String with Int.